Issues when mixing expo-notifications + react-native-firebase
I have a setup very similar to this previous OP.
In short, I use the expo-server-sdk to send out a notification, and I'm able to receive and handle this notification if my app is foregrounded or backgrounded. In the event that it is backgrounded, I use expo-task-manager, again, as in the question that I linked to above.
This works as expected, however I needed a mechanism to bring my app to the foreground, or at least wake it up, if a user received an incoming call. I'm using react-native-callkeep for all call-related functionality.
The OS in question is Android. I haven't gotten to fully implementing this for iOS yet.
expo-task-manager does not work if the app is terminated. It works if the app is either backgrounded or foregrounded, but if you quit/close the app, then expo-task-manager does not fire (specifically Notifcations.registerTaskAsync)
So, following the docs from react-native-callkeep:

In some case your application can be unreachable :

when the user kill the application
when it's in background since a long time (eg: after ~5mn the os will kill all connections).
To be able to wake up your application to display the incoming call, you can use https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-voip-push-notification on iOS or BackgroundMessaging from react-native-firebase-(Optional)(Android-only)-Listen-for-FCM-messages-in-the-background).

You have to send a push to your application, like with Firebase for Android and with a library supporting PushKit pushes for iOS.

So I've installed @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/messaging as per their documentation here and here.
After rebuilding my app, all notifications stopped coming in, even though I get a { status: 'ok' } when attempting to send out a notification. It just doesn't get delivered.
The only thing I haven't done from the docs is specify any config plugins. This is because, apparently, they are included by default for @react-native-firebase/app.
Uninstalling @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/messaging solves the unreceived notifications problem, but it just brings me back to the original issue of needing a mechanism for waking the terminated app.
My app.config.ts:
export default {
    expo: {
        name: '. . .',
        ios: {
            googleServicesFile: './GoogleService-Info.plist',
            bundleIdentifier: 'com.me.app', // same as in google-services.json
            '. . .'
        },
        android: {
            googleServicesFile: './google-services.json',
            package: 'com.me.app', // same as in google-services.json
            '. . .'
        },
        plugins: [
            '@react-native-firebase/app',
            [
                'expo-build-properties',
                {
                    android: {
                        usesCleartextTraffic: true,
                    },
                    ios: {
                        useFrameworks: 'static',
                    },
                },
            ],
            '@config-plugins/react-native-webrtc',
            '@config-plugins/react-native-callkeep',
            '. . .'
        ],
        runtimeVersion: {
            policy: 'appVersion',
        },
        extra: {
            eas: {
                projectId: '. . .',
            },
        },
        updates: {
            url: '. . .',
        },
    },
};

What am I doing wrong here? Did I overlook something during the installation process or does @react-native-firebase not play nice with expo-notifications?
